# Azure DevOps Default Agent showing offline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

We have one "default" agent that is used in our build pipelines. However, it sometimes shows as "offline" even though the VM is up, and running.

I followed the guide which states I go to C:\azagent\A4 and run.cmd. However, I get the following error when I do.

I also looked at the services and the service was set to "automatic (delayed", and switched it to automatic.

I have also ensured that the agent is running the latest version.

What else can be done to see what the issue is? any other diagnosing advices?

[image]

Comment: Did you check available space?

Comment: This path: "C:\azagent\A4" is used to deployment groups. If you want to run your self-hosted agent, please search the correct folder.

Comment: What would the correct folder be, do you know?

Comment: It depends on which folder you downloaded the agent to. If you cannot find it, you can download and install a new one.